# What are the best practices related to managing keys used in git checkout for ansible?

Tags: django, deployment, travis-ci, ansible

Currently I am writing a playbook to deploy my Django application. There is nothing particularly revolutionary or secret sauce about it so I decided to open source it. The only thing I want to keep secret is of course the ssh key I use for deployment.

1. What are some of the strategies to deal with this ?
2. I would also like to use Travis-CI for testing. When using Travis to test the whole deployment what would be the best way to deal with keys ?

Some tips is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently started an open source ansible infrastructure approach with encrypted secrets and Travis CI testing ([GitHub link](https://github.com/himate/himate-infrastructure)).

I used [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) to encrypt the secrets. For each project [Travis creates a key pair](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) and with the help of the [travis-client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) you can use it to securely set the vault password within the Travis build environment.

### Your case with an ansible-vault approach

In your particular case (you only want to deploy one secret key), there are 2 easy ways to encrypt the key secret with `ansible-vault`.

**1st approach: Encrypt the static key file**

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=vault_pass ansible-vault encrypt <key_file>
```

Then with the following task you could copy it to the node:

```
- copy: 
    content={{ lookup('pipe', 'ansible-vault --vault-password-file vault_pass view <key_file>') }}
    dest=/<deploy_user>/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `lookup` workaround is necessary, since `ansible-vault` was designed to encrypt/decrypt `.yml` variable files and it does not automatically decrypt static files or templates during a rollout.

**2nd approach: Place key in variable and encrypt var file**

Another approach would be to add your private key to a `.yml` file (and encrypt it like above), which can then be decrypted on the fly by ansible:

*secrets.yml*

```
private_key: |
  <copy-key-here>
```

You can then reference that variable in a task.

Finally, both approaches can be rolled out via:

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=vault_pass ansible-playbook -i <inventory-file> <playbook-file>
```

Now you need to share your `vault_pass` (or a password to decrypt the `vault_pass` file) with Travis. This is very well documented in the Travis link above. In the last section I provide an article which also explains how to do that.

### Digging deeper

Even though it might be a little out of scope for your problem at hand, I'd like to share some more thoughts about this topic.

**Security concerns**

While testing with Travis is quite comfortable, one major problem though is that you are still handing over your secrets to the Travis environment (and obviously if Travis gets compromised, your secrets are gone) - so I suggest that maybe it is safer to deploy/rollout fake data in your Travis rollout tests. The project I provided above is still in early stages and does not contain any real production secrets (yet), but I will design my provisioning in a way that I can easily deploy fake data in my Travis rollouts. Also, ensure that you do not log too much in Travis (since for open source repos, the travis build logs are open source too). You can avoid logging with the `no_log: yes` variable inside a playbook.

**HashiCorp Vault**

Another very interesting project for handling secrets comes from HashiCorp: [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) (not to be mistaken with `ansible-vault`!) I didn't have the time to look into it closer yet, but it looks very promising and seems like a good idea for bigger setups.

**External article**

Here is a [more detailed article](http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2016/04/02/testing-ansible-ansible-vault-travis-ci/) about using `ansible-vault` with Travis CI (also for cases in which you wish to encrypt sensitive templates or other static files, which requires some small workarounds since `ansible-vault` was only designed to encrypt `.yml` files containing variables). It also briefly discusses the issue of sharing secrets with external services. (Secret management is a very interesting topic and I am still adjusting my approaches, so the article is still kind of in the making, but most of the ideas are already provided there)

Comment: https://github.com/jhaals/ansible-vault is a little plugin for Ansible that provides direct support for pulling secrets out of (Hashicorp) Vault.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov This looks indeed very nice! The only thing left to do now is setting up the vault server. I will try that soon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @XiingChiamiov, great post. Very helpful. In your [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/himate/himate-infrastructure/blob/master/.travis.yml), you have `env.global.secure` and `slack.rooms.secure`. These both look like secure access keys/passwords...is there a way to encrypt these 2 variables so that they appear as hashes in `.travis.yml`?